# Jenkins: Unable to read parameters in Multijob downstream using parameterized trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Running A multijob task with 1 phase(task runs on slave)

Method 1: I wrote a properties file in the parent task by executing shell before the phase 1 task starts execution

`echo "days_to_pull_and_verify=1000" > /tmp/importxx`

`cat /tmp/importxx`
Did the below in the phase 1 task
[image]
In  phase 1 I am not able to access `${days_to_pull_and_verify}` or `$days_to_pull_and_verify` but the file exists and also the task starts to run

Method 2: Added `Predefined Parameters` in config like `days_to_pull_and_verify=1000`
but not able to access those variables in the phase 1 task execute shell section

Method 3: Checked current build parameters check box but still not able to access those parameters in the phase 1 task execute shell

Am I missing something very simple?

Comment: it's happening the same to me..did you fix it by now?

Comment: I don't know what was screwed up but then I recreated the whole environment and it was fixed